# Best practice for writing code in php for foreach->foreach->if(1st loop id == 2nd loop id)->result

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

First loop table

```
user_id | fname | lname
1       | first | emp
2       | second| emp
3       | third | emp
```

Second loop table

```
shift_id | employee_id
1        | 1
2        | 2
3        | 2
```

```
if($employees)
{
  foreach ($employees as $employee) 
  {
    if($employee['user_id'] == $shift['employee_id'])
    {
      echo ucwords($employee['fname']. ' ' .$employee['lname']);
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the right result but I think there is some better way of writing this.

Comment: There is only 1 loop in your code.

Comment: you can use join query

Comment: you can write join on database side. It will fetch only those records which matches your condition. No need to create any loops .

Comment: What is your current database query to fill $employees?

Comment: join query not a better suggestion for the query because that will be pressure on a DB. so you did right but I have interested to know what have you used the just single loop for that?

Comment: @rowmoin Using a Join query is a far superior method. One DB trip VS two. Simpler Loop... Let the Database do the heavy lifting as its designed to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some test code I whipped up to test this from the information provided for this "Demonstration Code".

Note: I have used the mysqli class for the database (instantiating $db ) and have excluded the SQL Table setup.

What you would have had is something along the lines of this...

**Case 1 - The original**

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'test', 'phptutorials_st26');

echo '<h2>Create $employees </h2>';
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $db->query($query);
$employees = $result->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);
var_dump($employees);


echo '<h2>Create $shifts </h2>';
$query = "SELECT * FROM shifts";
$result = $db->query($query);
$shifts = $result->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);
var_dump($shifts);


echo '<h2>Using foreach on $employees and $shifts</h2>';

if ($employees) {
    foreach ($employees as $employee) {
        foreach ($shifts as $shift) {
            if ($employee['user_id'] == $shift['employee_id']) {
                echo ucwords($employee['fname'] . ' ' . $employee['lname']);
                echo '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Result from the above is

```
First Emp
Second Emp
Second Emp
```

**Case 2 - Using a Join**

Well using a join, as everyone has already stated, is the way to go...

```
$sql = "SELECT u.user_id, u.fname, u.lname, s.shift_id
          FROM users AS u
             JOIN shifts AS s ON(u.user_id = s.employee_id)
       ";

$result = $db->query($sql);
$employees = $result->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);

// To see what comes out because we always check things.
var_dump($joined_result);
```

(Don't ask me why I love using very abbreviated aliases for the table names! It's just "a thing".)

Then your "loop" simply becomes...

```
echo '<h2>Using foreach on join</h2>';
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
    echo ucwords($employee['fname'] . ' ' . $employee['lname']);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

And the result is...

```
First Emp
Second Emp
Second Emp
```

Case 2 - has reduced the code and only requires 1 Trip to the Database.

Does that help you any?

Answer (score 4):

You can use joins in table. Left join means that the user line has to exists (because: LEFT) and the shifts enty is optional.

```
SELECT user.user_id, user.fname, user.lname, shifts.shift_id
FROM yourUserTable AS user
LEFT JOIN yourShiftsTable AS shifts ON(user.user_id = shifts.employee_id)
```

Now you get it in your initial array, as if you'd select it as one row from a table and no longer need to do tricks in PHP to combine information. If you can, always try to get the database to manage data, it does that *way* faster than PHP can.

*Please note, the query could be a little off, I just wrote this out of the top of my head.*

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way also. Its a little shorter.

```
SELECT TABLE1.FNAME, TABLE1.LNAME, TABLE2.EMPLOYEE_ID 
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2 
WHERE TABLE1.USER_ID = TABLE2.EMPLOYEE_ID;
```